# How to iterate over an single array values in the request body

Tags: javascript, express

I have one array from req.body. I need to loop through and fetch the value like(quantity_1 as one separate data and  quantity_2 as separate data) How to fetch like this and My Array from req.body is:

```
 { quantity_1: '9',
  item_name_1: 'Event Cap Nike',
  amount_1: '599',
  shipping_1: 'undefined',
  shipping2_1: 'undefined',
  quantity_2: '1',
  item_name_2: 'Plaza',
  amount_2: '1000',
  shipping_2: 'undefined',
  shipping2_2: 'undefined',
  cmd: '_cart',
  upload: '1',
  bn: 'MiniCart_AddToCart_WPS_US',
  business: ' ',
  currency_code: 'INR',
  return: ' ',
  cancel_return: ' ' }
```

Comment: req.body looks like an object and not an array

Answer (score -2):

Actually, this is not an `array` but an object and you can iterate and `console.log` its values by using `for ... in` loop like this:

```js
const myObj = { quantity_1: '9',
  item_name_1: 'Event Cap Nike',
  amount_1: '599',
  shipping_1: 'undefined',
  shipping2_1: 'undefined',
  quantity_2: '1',
  item_name_2: 'Plaza',
  amount_2: '1000',
  shipping_2: 'undefined',
  shipping2_2: 'undefined',
  cmd: '_cart',
  upload: '1',
  bn: 'MiniCart_AddToCart_WPS_US',
  business: ' ',
  currency_code: 'INR',
  return: ' ',
  cancel_return: ' ' }

for(let key in myObj) {
    if(key in ["quantity_1", "item_name_1", "amount_1"]) {
        console.log(myObj[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why that downvotes?!!? Don't know if someone is doing it on purpose or so, but it's not funny ... It's the correct answer and I don't get what is wrong ...

Comment: Thanks.....I need to take quantity_1,item_name_1, amount_1 only means what i need to do?

Comment: I'll edit it, give me a second

Comment: @DvThiyanesh I added one `if` statement inside `for` loop to show only your required values

Comment: Not exact one if there are 20 quantity and their name and price then to fetch it

Answer (score -2):

1. This is not an array. This is an object.
2. You can use `Object.keys` method among others to iterate the object properties.

```js
 var myObj = { quantity_1: '9',
  item_name_1: 'Event Cap Nike',
  amount_1: '599',
  shipping_1: 'undefined',
  shipping2_1: 'undefined',
  quantity_2: '1',
  item_name_2: 'Plaza',
  amount_2: '1000',
  shipping_2: 'undefined',
  shipping2_2: 'undefined',
  cmd: '_cart',
  upload: '1',
  bn: 'MiniCart_AddToCart_WPS_US',
  business: ' ',
  currency_code: 'INR',
  return: ' ',
  cancel_return: ' ' }
  
  Object.keys(myObj).forEach(prop => {
  
      console.log(myObj[prop]);
  })
```

Comment: This question should be closed ,its a duplicate

Comment: Of course. That is why I marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?